# How can I get the text value of a button in Roblox Lua

Tags: button, lua, roblox

How can I add the text value of clicked button to display. Currently, only first button functions and prints nicely.

```
local Key = Instance.new("Part");
local DisplayVal =""

Key = workspace.KeyPads.Keypad1.SurfaceGui.keys;
Key.MouseButton1Click:connect(function(hit)
    
    DisplayVal = DisplayVal .. Key.Text
    workspace.KeyPads.Keypad1.SurfaceGui.display.Text = DisplayVal
end)
```

Comment: Why do you use the same variable name for two different instances?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have this code copied inside each button on the keypad.

That means that each button is using their own version of `DisplayVal`. When you hit one button, that button's `DisplayVal` gets set. If you hit the same button again, I'm sure it would work properly, but as soon as you switch to a different button it would revert back to the empty string.

So to fix this, why not just use the text from the display directly, rather than holding onto a variable version?

```
local Gui = workspace.KeyPads.Keypad1.SurfaceGui
local Display = Gui.display
local Key = Gui.keys

Key.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local DisplayText = Display.Text .. Key.Text
    Display.Text = DisplayText
end)
```